# TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones Method - include daylight savings time etc?

Tags: c#, timezone

I'm doing this:

```
var tzs = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
TimezoneList = tzs.Select(tz => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = tz.DisplayName,
    Value = tz.Id
}).ToArray();
```

to get time zone info.

It works well, though we need it to be sensitive to daylight savings time (eg British Summer Time, rather than UTC or Eastern Time vs Eastern Daylight Time). Anybody know how to do it with this method, or know a different method of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: The `TimeZoneInfo` objects returned by the first line of your code already are sensitive to daylight saving time.  All the methods such as `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` and others will take DST into account if applicable, depending on the timestamp you pass in.  So - what is your question??

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know a timezone support daylight saving you can simply use this code.

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
bool isSupportsDaylightSavingTime = timeZone.SupportsDaylightSavingTime;
```

But if your question is about after converting the time zone of one date to another, daylight time is considered and applied or not **the answer is yes**.

To convert a timezone for a date you can use the code below

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, timeZone);
```

Comment: Thanks. What I want to do is record that a user is in a timezone including daylight saving. So set them to 'British Summer Time' - then find out the date/time in 'British Summer time' right now (not the time at UTC right now).

So can I set a timezone that will automatically get the DST adjusted date/time when required? They don't appear in the list, how would I do that?

Comment: I understood. for example you want to get the current time by British TimeZone and DST adjusted. to do that convert your date to British Standard Time like my code to convert UTC to Eastern Standard Time. British TimeZone Id is 'GMT Standard Time'. the result is DST adjusted

Comment: Thanks. So it's a 2 step process  - I can't have those time zones in the list and selectable?

Comment: Yes, you can. your code is correct and when the user selects a timezone you simply get the timezone by Id and convert your date like my second sample code. the result is DST adjusted.

Comment: Thanks - although I'd like the DST aware items in the list - and not the DST unaware items. They should always be the time in a geographic location adjusted for DST as appropriate. Any idea how to do that? (you may also have 2 different cities in the same 'timezone' but one changes to DST and one doesn't for example.

Comment: @niico - Perhaps you are confused because of the wording in the time zone identifier.  Rest assured, `"GMT Standard Time"` is the Windows time zone ID for the UK, inclusive of both GMT in the winter and BST in the summer.  The adjustment rules contained in the underlying time zone data know when to use each, depending on the date being converted.  See also [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), under the section about the Microsoft Windows Time Zone Database - the bullet starting with: *"Identifiers and names are confusing and assigned haphazardly..."*